# Hiding characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In the title view of my view controller, I have this string:

```
@"the guy 1137937485"
```

Is there a way to hide the number, or in other words hide the last 10 characters of the string? By hide I do not mean delete. I still need the characters; I just want the user to not see them. The numbers are random but always 10 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new `NSString` without the last 10 characters.

```
NSString *newstring = [yourstring substringToIndex:[yourstring length] - 10];
```

Comment: but I said I do not want to delete the numbers, I just want to hide the characters in the string

Comment: You can still keep the old string around and just use the new one in your presentation.

Comment: @Alessandro: keep the original, use `newstring` for presenting to the user.